# How to enter a value from data grid view into a label?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Basic Express.
What I want to do is to allow user to select a row from data grid view that is connected to MS SQL database. When the user selects a row and then clicks on a button, the so-called search form closes. Now, what I want to do is to copy the values of two out of four columns in data grid view to a label on a different form, so that a user can be sure that he selected the right row before proceeding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution! If anyone needs it, here it is:

```
    form.Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value & " " & DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value
```

This code will replace the text in a label with the values from columns with indexes 1 and 2 divided by a blank space.